# How to make jmeter report dashboard show more than three percentile?

Tags: jmeter

In the jmeter dashboard I can see three percentile values and I know I can change them by setting the three properties below in the user.properties file.

```
aggregate_rpt_pct1=50
aggregate_rpt_pct2=60
aggregate_rpt_pct3=70
```

However, I need these too:

```
aggregate_rpt_pct1=80
aggregate_rpt_pct2=90
aggregate_rpt_pct3=95
aggregate_rpt_pct3=99
```

But when I add all of them it only shows three of them. It totally ignores the rest. Is there a way to increase the number of percentiles the dashboard shows? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter support only 3 percentiles in dashboard.

To see more, You will have [regenerate dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) several times, or request an enhancement in https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=JMeter